# How do you keep rodents out of your vehicle when it's parked at the trailhead?

Tags: animal-behaviour, prevention

On some backpacking trips a car could be left for a couple of weeks, what can I do to ensure that when I return the mice aren't inside and the squirrels are leaving the wiring alone?

Comment: Let them chew on the stored butane canisters first.  That will take care of them.

Comment: you can always bring your cat... no need to bring food... :)

Comment: All the times I've parked my truck in the backcountry and left it, I've never once worried about animals getting into it, or heard anyone ever mention it before.

Comment: Yeah what makes you think this would be an issue?

Comment: @Liam The six wires and vacuum hoses that I am splicing after some squirrels got in :)

Comment: Seriously [delinquint squirrels](http://www.tutorialking.eu/images/large/1374-army-squirrel-photoshop-manipulation-tutorial.jpg) in wyoming! :)

Comment: @ShemSeger At some California trailheads marmots are so bad people circle their cars with chicken wire. Here's an example http://www.patagonia.com/blog/2010/08/marmots-and-men/ They are apparently attracted by anti-freeze but chew wires, too, in their search for it. I'd guess you could try some kind scent product that is a predator to rodents.

Comment: @topshot If it were me, I'd probably just leave a dish antifreeze out for them, then they would have to go digging in my vehicle for it.

Comment: I suspect the rangers would be having a nice chat with you then. ;)

Comment: We had a problem with a rat once -- he took all our freeze dried food and all our maps.  Human rat.

Comment: @ShemSeger I clicked on this question upon seeing it because I had this happen once. I did not know this was a concern either until I had a car that was severely messed up by mice.

Comment: I normally give one of the local kids 20 piso a day for such. About 40 cents U.S. He keeps the rodents away from your vehicle till you return.

Answer (score 10):

Stop coating your wires with peanut butter!

In all seriousness though, squirrels can and will eat wires.  However this is a very unlikely occurrence, as noted by ShemSeger in comments.  I have known exactly ONE person it ever happened to and the car was at their house, not a trail head.

You could discourage most pests by putting mothballs in your engine compartment (after it has cooled).  Of course mothballs are toxic and it would be vitally important to remove them before you drive away lest you poison yourself on the fumes.  Most other rodent deterrents are lethal (traps, bait) and it would be pretty unethical IMO to use those in this situation.

Outdoor activities all have risks and you have to weight the likelyhood of the risk coming to fruition against the cost and effort of prevention.

Comment: Chili can be used to deter rodents in some situations (e.g. bird seed) and is non toxic. I've seen a spray product but can't remember what it was sold for. You would want to make sure it doesn't come out of your air vents while driving of course.

Comment: when my dog was a puppy, we used to left her in the garage during the day. One day she discovered she could nibble the fluid hose of the front break of the motorbike. I saw it one evening and next morning I put some peri peri sauce around the place she was nibbling only to discover her liking the sauce minute later. :)

Comment: @ChrisH -- I've had mixed results with chili.  I once coated my entire porch in powdered cayenne only to find rodent tracks in it the next day :/

Comment: I've used mothballs in boat engines and other closed compartments, where the boat was sitting on land for a few months on an island with a rat problem. Never had anything nesting in or chewing on the mothballed engine. People who didn't take precautions usually did have chewed wires.

Comment: Dryer sheets are also a deterrent to rodents and a bit less toxic than mothballs.  I use them in my electric car.  Rodents love the warmth that comes from the charging batteries so it is very difficult to keep rodent free.

Comment: @ChrisH and Russell, It's very important to stay away from chili powder and cayenne. Many reputable studies have shown that they cause breathing problems, blindness, disfiguration and death in mammals, rodents and birds. I don't want to describe the mechanics of it, because it's gruesome and sad. As you mentioned, mothballs are also toxic, but not just to people. I know the answer here is focused on humane ways to handle the problem, so I thought I'd add this.

Comment: @Sue, could you post a link please? Especially relating to birds as chilli added to bird seed was being suggested by some reputable sources as a squirrel deterrent not long ago.

Comment: @RussellSteen You now have heard of it happening to at least 3 people (assuming you haven't already gotten to three in the last 11 months). Whoever you meant, OP, and me. I clicked this question because I had this problem. Mice chewed stuff up and pooped everywhere. My mechanic informed me that he has seen this from time to time, and that if the mice pooped in the ventilation that I could cause myself health problems by continuing to use it, so I sold it at a steep loss because of the condition. I say mice since that's what my mechanic said, but I don't know for sure what it actually was.